# Getting an error while trying to limit my time on youtube

Tags: python, datetime

this is my code:

```
import requests
import pytz
import datetime
import requests

def is_website_active():
    try:
        response = requests.head("https://www.youtube.com/")
        if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
            return True  # Status code in the 200s indicates an active website
        else:
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False  # Request error, website is not active


def get_website_start_date():
    try:
        response = requests.head("https://www.youtube.com/")
        if 'Date' in response.headers:
            server_time = response.headers['Date']
            server_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(server_time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
            # Set the server's timezone to UTC
            server_time = pytz.utc.localize(server_time)
            
            # Convert to Pacific Time (PT)
            pacific_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
            server_time_pt = server_time.astimezone(pacific_timezone)
            
            return server_time_pt
        else:
            return "Date header not found in the response."
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"
start_Date = get_website_start_date()

while True:
    if is_website_active():
        min_difference = datetime.datetime.now()-start_Date
        print(min_difference)
```

to get it to work you need to go to cmd promt and write "pip install request pytz

I am getting an error

My end goal is to block me from being on youtube for to long
but right now I just want to destroy this error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`?

That occurs because `now()` isn't aware of the timezone, you're able to fix it by passing the timezone to `datetime.datetime.now()`.

```py
while True:
    if is_website_active():
        min_difference = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))-start_Date
        print(min_difference)
```

Also, where you check if the response status code is 2xx, you're able to do it like that:

```py
def is_website_active():
    try:
        response = requests.head("https://www.youtube.com/")
        return response.ok() # Will return True if status code is equal to 2xx
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return False  # Request error, website is not active
```

Comment: it worked thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted :)